# Android sdk edit big images

Tags: android, image, process

i have made an image editing application for android and i want to edit large images that there is not available memory size to load all of their data into it. Is there any library that provide api that load and stores part of an image so i can have an edit only a portion that fits the memory? Photoshop for android can edit images up to 1600x1600, how this is possible?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use matrices to scale the image, take a look at this [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.3.3_r1/com/android/camera/ViewImage.java?av=f) Is hard to understand, but it might bring you some light.

Comment: scaling and view is not a problem. The edit and the store are

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BitmapRegionDecoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html) to elaborate blocks of the large image.